# If $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are both factors of $H(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, polynomials, contest-math

$P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are both quadratic polynomials and both are factors of a cubic polynomial $H(x)$ such that:

$$H(x) = (x - a)P(x) \space \text{AND} \space H(x) = (x - b)Q(x)$$

> For distinct $a,b$ then $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ must have a root in common. Why?

Comment: Quartic polynomial? It seems to be that h(x) seems to be a cubic.

Comment: yes sorry, it is cubic

Comment: Hint: $H(a) = 0 \implies Q(a) = 0\implies Q(x) = (x-a)\hat{Q}(x)$ where $\hat{Q}$ is a linear polynimial. Do the same for $x=b$ and compare.

Comment: @NotALoner Why not?

Comment: Taking your argument further: Assume $\hat{Q}(x), \hat{P}(x)$ don't share a root in common, then $H(x) = m(x-a)(x-b)(x-c) = n(x-a)(x-b)(x-d), c \neq d$, then $a,b,c,d$ are the roots of $H$  and $H$ must have degree $\geq 4$, contradiction !

Answer (score 1):

In this case, let the roots of $h(x) = r_1, r_2, r_3$. Then if one of them was $a$, say $r_1$, then the polynomial $P(x)$ has its roots $r_2, r_3$.

On the other hand, if $b$ is distinct from $a$ one of its roots will be $r_2$ (it will be one of $P(x)$'s roots) and the polynomial $q(x)$ will still have two roots. One of these two roots is $P(x)$'s second root. Hence they share one common root.

This can be thought of as an application of the Pigeonhole Principle which is explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).